# Is there a hypernym for enzymes that "cut" other molecules?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, enzymes

I have searched on Google for a hypernym/umbrella term that encompasses all enzymes whose function is to cut other molecules, but I have yet to find such a term. The term I am looking for would encompass enzymes groups such as proteases, nucleases, and lipases.

Is there such a term in molecular biology?

Comment: Aren't all enzymes named with the suffix "-ase"?

Comment: Oh yeah d'oh. Don't know why I forgot that. Ignore me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hydrolases can "cut" other molecules using hydrolysis (see proteases), and Lyases can catalyze "cutting" with other reactions (see aldolases). These are umbrella terms for families of enzymes classified by function.

I think [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4576142/) is a fair open-access review of enzyme classification.

Comment: Please provide links to the EC classification or the like to support your assertion. You may be right, but how is anyone to know?

Answer (score 0):

The term you want is "scission enzyme".  Scission is from Latin scissio, the same root as for scissors.  This is a broad umbrella term which does not speak to mechanism of cutting.

Comment: Never heard this used. Please support your suggestion by citations and links, otherwise they are likely to be flagged as low quality.

Comment: Also never heard this. Strongly doubt it is a common term.

Comment: I appreciate you 2 asking for clarification rather than just down voting.  [Here is a google search with 632 uses of the term](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=%22scission+enzyme%22&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=active&as_filetype=&as_rights=). It is such a broad category that the term is not that useful, which may be why you two are unfamiliar with it.